# One master can has how many detail objects?

Tags: object, salesforce, master-detail

I know that one object can only has two master-detail relationships Means One detail object only has 2 masters. But I have one doubt that one master can has how many detail objects?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only limit for lookup relationship is " maximum number of custom fields allowed"
according to this [document](http://na14.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/relationships_considerations.htm)